# how to verify XML that include specific tags

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl, xml

is it possible to check by xmllint if xml include the follwing tags:

1. Name
2. uniq_String
3. Version

example of xml with three tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- tasks configuration file -->
<tasks>
   <Name>destry_srorage_luns</Name>
   <uniq_String>destry_srorage_luns run once at day</uniq_String>
    <Version>14.03.23</Version>
```

if not by using **xmllint**

what the other alternative to check tags are defined in xml with awk/sed/perl oneliner?

expected output in case xml include both tags - Name , uniq_String , Version

```
 XML_VALID=TRUE
```

expected output in case xml NOT include both tags - Name , uniq_String , Version

```
 XML_VALID=FALSE
```

Comment: do you have a [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) for this XML file?  `xmllint` can check if an XML file is valid according to its DTD (which is the "correct" way to check if an XML file is valid.  All other methods are essentially hacks of varying degrees of quality - RomanPerekhrest's xmlstarlet version is a very high-quality hack because it uses a tool that parses and queries XML. xmlstarlet can also validate XML.  A few simple regpexp matches would be low-quality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
if xmlstarlet sel -Q -t -c "//*[Name and uniq_String and Version]" input.xml; then
    echo "XML_VALID=TRUE"
else 
    echo "XML_VALID=FALSE"
fi
```

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416

---

**`xmllint`** alternative solution:

```
if xmllint --xpath "//*[Name and uniq_String and Version]" input.xml &>/dev/null; then
    echo "XML_VALID=TRUE"
else 
    echo "XML_VALID=FALSE"
fi
```

Comment: ok fine , but in case - Xmlstarlet not installed on my Linux do you have alternative solution with awk/sed/perl ?

Comment: @yael, see my update

Comment: what a great solution you are really brilliant